# How do I know how much power is left on my external battery?

Tags: battery-life, ups

Our IT consultant persuaded us to add an external battery pack to our dying UPS, rather than buy a new one.

The UPS still counts down from about 4 minutes after the AC power is removed, but continues to power-up the equipment for at least another 30 minutes from the external battery, after reaching zero.

However, the display panel remains at 0% and we have no way of knowing how long the external pack would last us.

The IT consultant told us the same as what we have been told by the manufacturer; that this is by design! (As in *documented bug are features*.)

**Are there any methods to measure the external battery's remaining juice?**

Comment: What brand and model UPS and external battery?

Comment: Ask the IT consultant?

Comment: @Dave, did that. He sent me the manufacturer's response. :-(

Comment: @ChristianIsaksson - the UPS is an "Advice TopVision Top 1.5K RM" and the external battery is a sealed box with a cable to the UPS, a fuse and a sticker saying model:BBRN3U-7212, Output: 72VDC. One can find the UPS on Google, but not the "black box".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open and test it. An **electrical battery discharger** can be used to determine battery capacities and to help identify defective batteries or cells in battery sets.

> **Laptop/PC Interface** [Lester Electrical battery dischargers](http://www.lesterelectrical.com/products/dischargers/) can be connected to a computer via the RS-232 serial port to display in
>   real-time, analyze, and archive discharge data.
>
> **Simple to Operate** To begin a discharge cycle, you connect the two alligator clamps to the battery or battery set and press the Start
>   button. Real-time data is available on the display. The discharge
>   cycle will automatically terminate based on battery voltage or time,
>   which are user programmable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a need to know with confidence how much power remains, you could use a digital voltmeter to read the voltage of the external battery (assuming it's lead-acid or gel cell, as most UPS batteries are).  Generally lead-acid chemistry is 2.2 V per cell when fully charge, dropping to about 2.0 V per cell when "discharged" -- discharging to lower voltage can reduce a battery's recharge cycle count.  This won't directly give you working time, but the voltage curve on this type of cell is almost linear, so you can read the range as a percentage of remaining capacity -- i.e., 2.1 V per cell is about 50% charge.

As others have said, you shouldn't depend on the UPS to continue working, but use the time it gets you to perform an orderly shutdown, so you don't wind up with damaged filesystems, lost data, or possibly even hardware damaged from an abnormal shutdown.  The time it takes to restart after a shutdown is nothing compared to the time to recover after a filesystem gets partially randomized by open files or an interrupted write.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in t[he Wikipedia entry on uninterruptible power supplies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply):

> The on-battery runtime of most uninterruptible power sources is
>   relatively short (only a few minutes) but sufficient to start a
>   standby power source or properly shut down the protected equipment.

You state:

> However, the display panel remains at 0% and we have no way of knowing
>   how long the external pack would last us.
>
> The IT consultant told us the same as what we have been told by the
>   manufacturer; that this is by design! (As in *documented bug are
>   features*.)

A UPS is generally meant to provide just enough power to shut down the attached equipment in a controlled manner, so the “…is by design” is a fully correct answer, to be interpreted as “You get the specified amount of time to shutdown your equipment, with guarantee.”

The fact that the UPS has capabilities beyond that, is your **guarantee** (the safety margin, crumple zone, …), and nothing that you should try turn to advantage in other ways.

Comment: I appreciate that philosophy, but: 1: I have no idea how long I have (though we tested it for 30 minutes) and bringing down all the VMs "just in case we're running out of power" is very time-consuming in a area with frequent outages. And more importantly (even using your approach) 2: How do I tell when the external batteries start getting old and have no power left?

Comment: ;-)  you have the manufacturer specified amount of time, regardless of what you measured - if you need more time, then you need to look into getting a replacement unit that has the appropriate level "guaranteed". If you begin measuring you might run into a situation where you have **too little time to actually *accomplish* a controlled shut down**.

Comment: 2) the UPS has electronics to re-charge the power storage, compare to how car-batteries behave (assuming the UPS uses LED-batteries), replace when you begin to doubt their capacity or at a shorter timed limit.